# how to call deleteuserdata or deleteprofile on skype bot

Tags: botframework

I tried typing /deleteprofile like I would in an emulator, but that does not seem to help. In emulator I tried the send system acticity->deleteUserData menu option to exercise my own piece of code for the system message. But in skype how can I invoke the system message deleteUserData?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the `ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData`in Skype is triggered when the user removes the Bot as contact from Skype.

If you want to emulate the /deleteprofile you can always grab the code from the [DeleteProfileScorable](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/DeleteProfileScorable.cs#L92-L96).

I've seen in [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2411) that the /deleteprofile wasn't working on Skype and that they implemented a reset command that does:

```
context.Reset();
context.ConversationData.Clear();
context.UserData.Clear();
context.PrivateConversationData.Clear();
await context.FlushAsync(CancellationToken.None);
```